# Android Tablet connecting to smb and get a list of files

Tags: android, file, uri, android-3.0-honeycomb, smb

im a complete noob to android and java but have wanted to learn for a while.

im trying to build a file browsing app which can view files and directories in a samba server or other file shares.

I'm trying to use uri.parse to initialize the uri of my samba server and then i want to convert the uri into a File type so i can essentially do file.list() to get a list of files/folders from the server.

heres what i found so far but im having issues with getting this running:

String[] list = null;
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smb://AG-24640/Users/Public/");

File file = new File(new URI(uri.toString()));

list = file.list();

Is there anything im doing wrong or is there an easier way of doing this? Is there anything i need to do to get the build of android to understand smb://  ?? im running android honeycomb 3.2

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Android supports Samba/CIFS out of the box, you'll probably need to use a 3rd party java library like: http://jcifs.samba.org/

Comment: What about google/samba-documents-provider? Could that be used?
 https://github.com/google/samba-documents-provider